# Why isn't data-title attribute updating in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS and Bootstrap's popover. I can successfully bind to `data-content` but not to `data-title`:

```
<li data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-title="{{'Memory limit' | l10n}}" data-content="{{'Memory available for the execution of one testcase, measured in MiB.' | l10n}}">
  <a><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i> {{task.memory_limit}} MiB</a>
</li>
```

This code yields:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

From dev-tools though, I can see `data-title="Limite di memoria"` so it worked, so I really don't understand why it isn't updating to the actual view. Also, from dev-tools I can see that there are two empty new attributes that I don't know (`data-original-title` and `title`).

Comment: Are you using the stock bootstrap JS library or a port such as AngularStrap or Angular Bootstrap?

Comment: @MikeRobinson: stock bootstrap.min.js (version 3.0.3)

Answer (score 4):

it's because that attribute is read whenever the Bootstrap Popover JavaScript executes, which is before Angular updates that binding.

If you want to use that feature, you're either going to have to roll your own directive, or find one. [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has a Popover implementation you might be able to use.

Comment: Thanks, I tried wrapping the popover enabling call `$(...).popover();` with a `$timeout` call (zero delay) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-title="'global.passwrules' | translate : {passwlen : user.user.passwLen}"
```

but `data-title` is evaluated before `user.user.passwLen` is read from the database. So I rewrote the `tooltip.js` and added `timeout`.

old **tooltip.js**

```
directivesModule
.directive('toggle', function($timeout){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      if (attrs.toggle=="tooltip"){
          $timeout(function() {
              $(element).attr( 'title', scope.$eval(attrs.title));
              $(element).tooltip();
          },0);
      }
      if (attrs.toggle=="popover"){
          $(element).popover();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

to my **tooltip.js**

```
directivesModule
.directive('toggle', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      if (attrs.toggle=="tooltip"){
         $(element).attr( 'title', scope.$eval(attrs.title));
         $(element).tooltip();
      }
      if (attrs.toggle=="popover"){
        $(element).popover();
      }
    }
  };
});
```